# Flask sending info with GET when POST specified

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am creating an online bookstore and am having trouble with one specific entry. When a user purchases a book they are able to rate it and this functionality works except for the first book they purchased. The function works with the POST method and the form passes in a book_id and a rating which I then enter into a database using SQLAlchemy. The HTML code to submit the form is as such

```
                <form action="/add_rating" method="POST">
                  <select name="rating" id="rating">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="3">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" id='adding_rating' name="book_id" type="submit" value='{{display_cart[book].book_id}}'>Rating</button>
                </form>
```

As you can see the method is set to POST. The background function/route to enter the rating into the database is as follows:

```
@app.route('/add_rating',methods=["POST"])
def add_rating():
    if "cart" not in session:
        flash("There is nothing in your cart.")
        return render_template("cart.html", display_cart = {}, total = 0)
    dict_of_books = {}

    ## getting user info
    user = User.query.get(session['user_id'])
    user_name = user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name
    ##Get order history by user_id
    order = get_order_history(session['user_id'])
    dict_of_books = {}
    total_price = 0
    for i in range(len(order)):
        total_price += order[i].total
        book = get_book_by_id(order[i].book_id)
        details = {'book_id': order[i].book_id, "title": book.title, "quantity": order[i].quantity, 'total': order[i].total}
        dict_of_books[i] = details

    book_id = request.form.get('book_id')
    ratings = request.form.get('rating')
    user_id = session['user_id']
    add_rating = create_rating(ratings,book_id,user_id)
    return render_template("rating.html", display_cart = dict_of_books, total = total_price, user_info = user_name)
```

Now when I rate the first book it is sending the information through GET into the URL, but all the other purchases are sending through POST. The output flask/sqlalchemy gives for the first book is `"GET /rating?rating=3&book_id=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 -` but for the rest of the books it is `"POST /add_rating HTTP/1.1" 200 -`. The /rating route is basically just getting information about purchased books and displaying to the page and I do not specify GET/POST in the route. In case the route is needed I will post below, but I cant imagine it being of use to this issue.

```
@app.route('/rating')
def rate_book():
    if "cart" not in session:
        flash("There is nothing in your cart.")
        return render_template("cart.html", display_cart = {}, total = 0)
    dict_of_books = {}
    ## getting user info
    user = User.query.get(session['user_id'])
    user_name = user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name
    ##Get order history by user_id
    order = get_order_history(session['user_id'])
    dict_of_books = {}
    total_price = 0
    for i in range(len(order)):
        total_price += order[i].total
        book = get_book_by_id(order[i].book_id)
        details = {'book_id': order[i].book_id, "title": book.title, "quantity": order[i].quantity, 'total': order[i].total}
        dict_of_books[i] = details


    return render_template("rating.html", display_cart = dict_of_books, total = total_price, user_info = user_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, it seems that I have added a "parent" form tag and within it added another form tag to handle the button press. By changing the first form (one without method="POST") to just a div tag, it fixed the issue.
Example,
Original:

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
          <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <form>
                ...
                        <form action="/add_rating" method="POST">
                          ...
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
          <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <div>
                ...
                        <form action="/add_rating" method="POST">
                          ...
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```